How to fix JMS-Serializer error "You must define a type for App\Entity\Article::$categories."
I want to use JMSSerializer in a Symfony 5 application without ORM and without Doctrine. I use a REST-API to fetch data from and want to deserialize them with JMS.
I have a class like this:
class Article {
    /**
     * @Type("App\Entity\Category")
     */
    public array $categories;

}
In my ArticleService, I do this:
return $this->serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), 'array<' . Article::class . '>', 'json');

JMS throws an Exception:
You must define a type for App\Entity\Article::$categories.

How to fix that? What is missing for JMS to operate correctly?
